# R - Error in UseMethod("groups") : no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I was using "count" to summarize the column of a dataframe. The column (`dataset$Nationality`) consists of nationalities that can occur more than once (eg. Swiss, German, French, Swiss, etc.). It worked fine, until it today suddenly produced an error message:

> Error in UseMethod("groups") : no applicable method for 'groups'
>   applied to an object of class "character".

I reinstalled dplyr but it still did not work.

For example:

```
dataset$Nationality consists of c("Swiss", "French","German","Swiss")
```

then

```
count(dataset$Nationality)
```

would give something like

```
Swiss,2, French, 1, German,1
```

Can somebody tell me what I could do to make it work again?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Shouldn't the code for `count` be `count(dataset, Nationality)`?

Comment: It works! Thanks. Strangely before it accepted the dataset$Nationality format.

Comment: @thixio Upvote and accept my answer if you think it is useful so that others know this is the right answer, thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Hope this Answers your Question.

If you are using "plyr" Library `library(plyr)`

Correct Syntax: `count(dataset$Nationality)`

If you are using "dplyr" Library `library(dplyr)`

Correct Syntax: `count(dataset, Nationality)`

If you are using Both, You will have to use the syntax of the library you added last.

Adding what Dzej Suggested:

We can also use a  specific library as well.

Syntax to use dplyr directly: `dplyr::count(dataset, Nationality)`

Syntax to use plyr directly: `plyr::count(dataset$Nationality)`

Answer (score 10):

If you mis-use `count()` inside  of a `group_by(...) %>% summarise(...)`, you will cause the error described in this question.

For example, this code will produce the error:

```
tibble %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  summarize(number_sightings = count(`duration (seconds)`))
```

`count()` (in `dplyr::count(..., ..., [...])` and `plyr::count(...)`) produces a "value count"; a list of values and the frequencies of the distinct values in the vector. (*vs* a single number showing the length of the vector )

In this my, I wanted the `n()` "summary function" instead  of `count()` (more info in the [`summarise` documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/summarise))

```
tibble %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  summarize(number_sightings = n())
```

Answer (score 6):

According to Ankit Gupta's answer:

If you are using both, plyr and dplyr, you can use specific library's function by providing library_name::function_name(params), ex:

```
plyr::count(dataset$nationality)
```

Answer (score 4):

Writing what I feel is a more complete answer that combines what Ankit and aosmith have said and adds to it.

`count()` in the dplyr package can be called from two different contexts. The first is what aosmith and Ankit have suggested, which calls `count()` with the data frame as the first argument, followed by the variable(s) you want to count, separated by commas.

```
count(df, var1)
```

or

```
count(df, var1, var2)
```

The second way you can do this is using the R pipe (`%>%`) to pass the data frame into `count()`.

```
df %>% count(var1)
```

or

```
df %>% count(var1, var2)
```

Failing to provide the data frame in either context will result in the 'no applicable method' error seen in the question.