# dplyr - No applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "character" using count()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some code, where I am trying to count the unique case-ids which are strings.

```
pt_agg_df <- filtered_df() %>% group_by(AE_AS_PREFERRED_TERM) 
    %>% summarize(case_count = count(SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID_VERSION)) 
      %>% arrange(-case_count)
```

I am getting the error:

```
! no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of
class "character"
```

Shouldn't I be able to count unique string values occurring in a group?

Comment: Try `filtered_df() %>% count(AE_AS_PREFERRED_TERM, SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID_VERSION))` or `filtered_df() %>% group_by(AE_AS_PREFERRED_TERM, SAPPHIRE_CASE_ID_VERSION)  %>% summarize(case_count = n())`, i.e. `count` is not meant for vectors. It expects a data.frame as its first argument.

Comment: Possible dups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872826/count-function-for-character-class-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986155/r-error-in-usemethodgroups-no-applicable-method-for-groups-applied-to

Comment: `count()` is it's own dplty verb. It should not be used *inside* a `summaize()`, it's used *in place of* a `summarize()`.

Comment: And it does a unique count?  If it comes after a group expression it does an aggregate?  @MrFlick

Comment: I would give it a try. See the `?count` help page for all the details.

Comment: n_distinct can be used in summarize @MrFlick